# Set Delegate for the Groovy Script With BaseScript

Tags: groovy

I have a following piece of code in my application that runs scripts

```
    CompilerConfiguration compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration();
    compilerConfiguration.setScriptBaseClass(DelegatingScript.class.getName());
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(compilerConfiguration);

    try {
        String scriptText = "";
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(resources[0].getInputStream())){
            scriptText = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        }

        DelegatingScript script = (DelegatingScript)shell.parse(scriptText);
        script.setDelegate(this.getDelegate());
        script.run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot read script resource: '" + filename + "': " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
```

It worked for Groovy scripts until I started refactoring some of the functionality into the `@BaseScript` class. So, for instance I have this Groovy class

```
package com.example.scripts

abstract class MyBaseScriptClass extends Script {
    int getTheMeaningOfLife() { 42 }
}
```

Then I have script

```
package scripts

import com.example.scripts.MyBaseScriptClass
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

@BaseScript MyBaseScriptClass baseScript

add(context.application, 'test', theMeaningOfLife )
```

It fails to run with error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scripts.Script1 cannot be cast to groovy.util.DelegatingScript
    at com.metlife.harmony.scripts.groovy.dsl.RunScript.call(RunScript.java:86) ~[classes/:?]
```

That is if I use `@BaseScript` in my class it fails to cast it to `DelegatingScript` ? Is there some work around that ?

Comment: just make MyBaseScriptClass extends DelegatingScript ? RunScript look like a custom code, who need to cast the script to DelegatingScript

Comment: No, extending `DelegatingScript` doesn't work. I need to cast script to delegating in order to set a delegate for it `script.setDelegate(this.getDelegate());` That was a way to pass around execution context - rather than settings Binding which would require settigns variables explicitly, I just use delegate mechanism.

Comment: i know, but @BaseScript override your setScriptBaseClass(DelegatingScript). the baseclass of your script is MyBaseScriptClass, and this isn't castable to DelegatingScript

Comment: Right, but `MyBaseScriptClass extends DelegatingScript` doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Actually error is different.  `theMeaningOfLife` returns `null` in my script.

Comment: it's probably because your delegate respond to the property without throwing missingPropertyException

Comment: Is it possible to make delegate from `script.setDelegate(this.getDelegate())` to be a delegate for `MyBaseScriptClass` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to summarize the comments :

`@BaseScript` override `setScriptBaseClass(DelegatingScript.class.getName())`.
MyBaseScriptClass didn't extends DelegatingScript, so the cast in RunScript fail.

To fix this error, you should change MyBaseScript to extends DelegatingScript.

```
abstract class MyBaseScriptClass extends DelegatingScript {
    int getTheMeaningOfLife() { 42 }
}
```

If you want to bypass the DelegatingScript, you should maybe check is script is an instanceof DelegatingScript ? If yes, set the delegate, if no, do nothing ?

Inside the script, you can try to change your delegate, but it will work only if the current delegate didn't override the `baseScript` property :

```
baseScript.delegate = baseScript
```

Comment: Neither of this helps me 100% though. If I extend `DelegatingScript` it does fix the casting error, but then all the properties I use in my script (the one that has `@BaseScript` anno) return null. 
After looking at the source code for `DelegatingScript` I found out that it is only properties that are being treated in this way. Methods calls work ok. So `theMeaningOfLife` in my script returns `null` but `getTheMeaningOfLife()` returns 42.

Comment: i suppose your delegate is a map or something equivalent. let it throw missingPropertyException if the key is not found. your delegate return null for getProperty("meaningOfLife")